# Tests with generic classes crash since swift 2.2

Tags: xcode, swift

Since the update to **Swift2.2** my tests crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xb6bc48)` at a line that looks like this:

```
let myLet = MyGenericClass<MyType>(some: 0, parameters: 1)
```

At the debug navigator I can see that it stops at

```
0 swift_initClassMetadata_UniversalStrategy
...snip... 
6 type metadata accessor for MyGenericClass<MyType>
7 MyClassTests.theTestIAmExecuting() -> ()
...snip...
```

It may have something to do that I import the classes with `@testable import MyApp` instead of adding all my tested classed to the test target.

Is anyone having the same issue? anyone got a way to solve this?

**UPDATE**

It also is crashing when I run my project now

Comment: I have the same problem! not a clue yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am struggling with similar problem, please see https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-815 (crash only for iOS7) and vote for this bug if it is the same problem

Comment: You have following possible solutions: make class non-generic, remove `value` property, swap `object` and `value` properties declarations,
initialize object in `init`.