# Issue with Swift 2.2 generics (Xcode 7.3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7.3, swift2

I've got a frustrating situation with Swift 2.2 (Xcode 7.3). To simulate it, just create a variable in a user defined, generic class, and reference that class from someplace else. For example:

```
class A<T> {
    let genVar = 1
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let myVar = A<Int>() // crash is here
}
```

If you will run this code on a device running iOS 7 (iPhone 4, in my case), it will crash on the attempt of creating a variable of generic type. Here are the first lines of the device crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00298910
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x006b1d64 0x4bd000 + 2051428
1   Phone                           0x001c76ec 0xab000 + 1165036
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x006b307c 0x4bd000 + 2056316
3   libswiftCore.dylib              0x006b2f70 0x4bd000 + 2056048
4   libswiftCore.dylib              0x006b0f24 0x4bd000 + 2047780
5   libswiftCore.dylib              0x006b107c 0x4bd000 + 2048124
6   Phone                           0x0014e730 0xab000 + 669488
7   Phone                           0x00129390 0xab000 + 517008
8   UIKit                           0x31e9d9c4 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 188
```

On iOS 8 and 9 simulators/devices, the code above works okay.

Is Swift support for iOS 7 going to be dropped in the near future?

Comment: [This question does not sufficiently describe the problem](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/), and I have voted to close.  You should at a minimum include your iOS 7 crash stack trace, as well as a description of *when* the app crashes.  Is it when the app loads?  When this view controller is first accessed?  When this property is accessed?

Comment: The question is edited.

Comment: You didn't add any useful information.  We need the symbols.  If the crash is happening on the declaration of an instance variable, then you need to show code that is initializing the class that contains the instance variable.  I can't reproduce this with what you've given me, and you've given no useful debugging information.

Comment: That's all I have. Xcode doesn't print anything to the console, it just sticks on the pointed line with BAD_ACCESS exception. All code is given in the question. Device is iPhone4 with iOS 7.1.2. The same code worked correctly at Xcode 7.2.

Comment: "Is iOS 7 near to be dropped?" Yes, you can see here https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/ that iOS 8 + iOS 9 are 95% of the devices.

Comment: It is very possible that this is a Swift 2.2 bug, and this would be an excellent bug report to Apple. But there's nothing _we_ can say about it. It's not a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is very hard to reproduce for most people since iOS 7 is difficult to simulate nowadays.

Comment: Probably related to [this bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-815) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201272/tests-with-generic-classes-crash-since-swift-2-2). I am having the same issue, half of my classes are generic and they seem to crash since the swift 2.2/Xcode 7.3 update

Comment: I repeat my opinion that this is a very important bug report but not any kind of Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Thanks all of you. I already posted this bug report, hope Apple will fix such bugs in the next Xcode release.

Answer (score 3):

I've been tripped up by what appears to be two bugs with Swift generics in iOS 7. Here's how to fix them.

Bug #1 - you must define a generic as the first property in your class before any others.

Example - this code fails:

```
public class TestIOS7<T> {

    private var x: Int?
}

let x = TestIOS7<String>()
```

But here's the workaround:

```
public class TestIOS7<T> {

    private var kludge: T?
    private var x: Int?
}

let x = TestIOS7<String>()
```

Bug #2: Class constraints seem completely broken.

Example - this code fails:

```
class ClassA<B: ClassB> { }

class ClassB { }

let x = ClassA <String>()
```

I have not found any workaround aside from removing the "ClassB" constraint and rewriting all the code to deal with the fact that basically, this language feature no longer exists. This is particular painful when you need to call an initializer of ClassB from ClassA - I had to rewrite that block with hardwired if/then/else for all my ClassB subclasses until Apple fixes this.

If someone does find a workaround to Bug #2 please let me know!

Comment: regarding Bug #2: the code should not compile, since ClassB is not an ancestor of String. So this behaviour is actually correct.

Comment: This works fine: `class ClassA<B: ClassB> { }` `class ClassB { }` `class ClassC: ClassB {}` `let x = ClassA <ClassC>()`

Answer (score 1):

As [this bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-815) suggests, you have following possible workarounds:

- make class non-generic
- remove `value` property
- swap `object` and `value` properties declarations
- initialize object in `init`

Probably the best workaround is to initialize object in `init`:

```
class A<T> {
    let genVar: Int
    init() {
       genVar = 1
    }

}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let myVar = A<Int>() // no crash
}
```

Comment: @alpsystems.com based on your answer, I think it may be a different bug. The example (which is bullet point 4) should work..

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue.

A work-around was discovered though that would at least let us support iOS7 without a significant rewrite.
It looks like all subclasses must also be generic so that the parent generic works correctly in iOS7.
The subclass's generic type does not matter and it does not need to be the parent's generic type.

I also posted this answer on the [bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-815) discussion simpleBob linked.

Example:

```
// This heavily pollutes the codebase, so let's keep track of it but using a common meaningless generic value so we can find and destroy later when we no longer support iOS7
protocol iOS7SwiftGenericFixProtocol {}
struct iOS7SwiftGenericFixType: iOS7SwiftGenericFixProtocol {}

class GenericClass<T> {
    var value: T?
    let attribute = 0
}

class GenericSubclass<Element: iOS7SwiftGenericFixProtocol>: GenericClass<Int> {
    let otherAttribute = 0
}

let _ = GenericSubclass<iOS7SwiftGenericFixType>()
```

Answer (score 0):

With Xcode 7.3.1, the only problem with my generic class was that it was inheriting from NSObject. Removing the inheritance was enough, the order of property declaration didn't matter.